# Tableau: Data visualization: Issue with animating over time

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

So my issue is as follows (I'm using Tableau 10.5):

I'm creating an animation of total count of medal winners per country (medal count - x-axis, countries - y-axis);
then I put the year in pages section to create animation of total winners over time for different countries.

My issue is that as the years are going by in the animation, the total count of medal winners are not adding upon the previous years and instead just displaying medal count for that year.

As an example: say for Country A in 2015 (2 medals), 2016 (3 medals), 2017 (5 medals).

Currently when I animate, I am getting 2 for 2015, 3 for 2016, 5 for 2017,
but I need it so that when I animate from 2015 to 2017, I need the medals to display as 2 for 2015, then 2+3 for 2016 and then 2+3+5 for 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your measure field on the viz and choose Quick Table Calc->Running Total. You may need to adjust the table calc settings like "compute using". If so, read about table calcs in the online help - especially the section on partitioning and addressing.

Comment: I was able to fix half of it by the quic table calc.Thx, but when i run the animation across the different years, If a country did not appear a particular year, it disappears from the visual. Do u no any way i can make the country remain filled in as i animate?